# How to make a list with datemarks on Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Just have such a view:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="datemark" data-date="1">Today</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="1">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="1">Item 3</div>

    <div class="datemark" data-date="2">Tommorow</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="2">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item" data-date="2">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

with such data:

```
data = [
    1: {
        human: 'Today',
        date: 1,
        items: [
            item1: {
                name: 'test',
                date: 1 // possible here
            },
            item2: {...},
        ]
    },
    2: {
        human: 'Tommorow',
        date: 2,
        items: [
            item1: {...},
            item2: {...},
        ]
    }
]
```

or it can be:

```
data = [
    item1: {
        name: 'test',
        date: 1 // possible here
    },
    item2: {
        name: 'other',
        date: 2 // possible here
    },
    ...
]
```

How to make it works and can be sorted desc/asc by datemarks and 'inside' datemarks range if it have different hours and minutes also?

Tried v-for but only simple lists, how with datemarks?

Thanks!

Comment: I already have the answer, but first, is it possible you can factor your data better, like using an array? And also, can you refactor the `item1`, `item2` into an array too?? @Андрей Мильнер

Comment: @kevlai22 made it, it can be two types of data, second is more good cause first written is the parsed from second where items splitted by date, date is a timestamp as you could guess, just used simple numbers for an example

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it like this, use a `computed` property instead, and you can see I used `slice`, it's because I want to copy the array instead of sorting the elements in place:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    order: 'ASC',
    list: [
        {
            name: 'item1',
            date: 1 // possible here
        },
        {
            name: 'item2',
            date: 2 // possible here
        },
        {
            name: 'item3',
            date: 3 // possible here
        },
        {
            name: 'test',
            date: 4 // possible here
        },
        {
            name: 'other',
            date: 5 // possible here
        }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
      sortedList() {
          return this.list.slice(0)
            .sort((a, b) => {
                if (this.order === 'ASC') {
                    return b.date - a.date;
                }
                return a.date - b.date;
            })
      }
  },
  methods: {
      toggleSort(type){
          this.order = type;
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="toggleSort('ASC')">ASC</button>
    <button v-on:click="toggleSort('DSC')">DSC</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="datemark" v-for="item in sortedList">
      <div class="item">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for your reference, if you're actually doing comparison on real dates, use this instead"

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```